# nginx docker is not finding my self signed ssl certificate

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to add a `docker-compose` script to write ssl keys into my mounted directory during the `entrypoint`script.

The files are clearly being written and do exist on `/etc/letsencrypt/staging/$domain/`

Yet nginx complains during startup:

```
2023/05/30 13:11:46 [emerg] 11#11: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/staging/example.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/staging/example.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx    | nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/staging/example.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/staging/example.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx exited with code 1
```

nginx.conf

```
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/staging/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/staging/example.com/privkey.pem;
```

docker-compose.yml

```
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: 'no'
    environment:
      keysize: 4096
      domains: example.om
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - /var/www/certbot:/var/www/certbot
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/acme-challenge.conf:/etc/nginx/acme-challenge.conf
entrypoint:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        echo "===================================================================================="
        echo 
        
        [ ! -d "/etc/letsencrypt" ] && mkdir /etc/letsencrypt

        if [ ! -f "/etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem" ]; then

          curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/certbot/certbot/master/certbot/certbot/ssl-dhparams.pem > "/etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem"
          ls /etc/letsencrypt
          echo 
        fi

        if [ ! -f "/etc/nginx/options-ssl-nginx.conf" ]; then

          curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/certbot/certbot/master/certbot-nginx/certbot_nginx/_internal/tls_configs/options-ssl-nginx.conf > "/etc/nginx/options-ssl-nginx.conf"
          ls /etc/nginx
          echo 
        fi

        for domain in $$domains; do

          echo    : $$domain \(keysize: $$keysize\)
          echo 

          if [ ! -d "/etc/letsencrypt/staging/$$domain" ]; then
            
            mkdir -p /etc/letsencrypt/staging/$$domain

            openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:$$keysize -days 1 -keyout "/etc/letsencrypt/staging/$$domain/privkey.pem" -out "/etc/letsencrypt/staging/$$domain/fullchain.pem" -subj "/CN=localhost"
            echo
            
          fi

          ls /etc/letsencrypt/staging/$$domain
          echo 

        done

        nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

there may be a few reasons why this isn't working:

- because i am writing files during entrypoint, the files may somehow not be accessible when starting nginx?
- i am mounting `nginx.conf` directly, which may cause the nginx folder to be empty?